# Extension tag in xsd not working for mono 1.9

Tags: mono

I am using the extension tag in my xsd to validate XML, this works fine in the .Net framework in my windows local machine. But in Mono 1.9 machine the extension tag does not work, it does not validate the xml. I did some R & D on this issue and in one site it was given this problem as a bug and gave the solution to it referring to install some patch to mono.Here is the link
http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-bugs@lists.ximian.com/msg62811.html
I completely do not understand how to solve this issue and how the above link would help me. I would be glad if anyone helps me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mono 1.9 is ~3 years old.  The patch is already included in more modern versions of Mono.  Upgrading is probably your best bet.